# Particular Expandable View visible at one time

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am making an app in which the 1st layout contains clickable List having 12 items
and on clicking of each item, the user goes to a new Activity that has Expandable list View.

And I have concerned the tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BkazaAeeW1Q

and do I need to make 12 Activities each containing an Expandable View or is it possible that one Activity containing 12 Expandable Views but only one Expandable view is visible at a time (and which among them  is visible will be dependent on Item clicked on the List View of 1st layout)

Hope I am able to make my point clear?

Answer (score 0):

Use List Fragment, by using fragment no need to create 12 activity ,you just replace the container with view.
Also we can make one expandable view at one time, check on child click and onGroupexpand method for that.